# C is converting string to hex

Tags: c, file, binary, hex

I'm trying to read simple binary 'hello world' file and write it to another file with string. For some reason, string, that I want to write, automatically converts to hex code and I can't do anything with it. How can I write string and binary to one file?

I'm getting this: **6c 69 6e 65 20 3d 20 4d 5a 90 00 03 00...**

But I want this: **line = 4d 5a 90 00 03 00...**

**6c 69 6e 65 20 3d 20** is a string "**line =**"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* in = fopen("hello.exe", "r");
    FILE* out = fopen("out", "w");

    if(in == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open in file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(out == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open out file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int c;
    fprintf(out, "line = ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        c = fgetc(in);
        fputc(c, out);
    }
    fclose(out);
    fclose(in);
}
```

Comment: If you want to read binary data, why don't open the input file in binary mode?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No matter, anyway it's converting string to hex

Comment: As for your problem, how do you *display* or *check* the data in the output file?

Comment: And if you don't want the ASCII codes for `"line = "` in the output file, why do you write it to the file?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want it in plain text, not in hex

Comment: Then again, ***how are you checking the contents of the file?*** What problem do you use? Perhaps it doesn't know how to treat the file, and displays it as an unknown binary file? What happens if you name the output file `"out.txt"`? Although then you will have problem with all the actual binary data which can't be displayed as text. Write a text file, and then write the binary data as hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The misunderstanding is that a file does not contain "text" or "hex" per se, it contains bytes. And what you will "see" depends on the way you look at it:

If you use a hex dump program, you will see hex values *only*.

If you use a program that puts out text, e.g. `echo`, you will see test *only* (yet some bytes will lead to weird symbols on the screen).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if it's a binary file you're reading, you should open it as a binary file `FILE* in = fopen("hello.exe", "rb");`.

Then, to write the hex codes you can use the [`fprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) function and the `X` conversion operator:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* in = fopen("hello.exe", "rb");
    FILE* out = fopen("out", "w");

    if(in == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open in file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(out == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open out file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    unsigned int c;
    fprintf(out, "line = ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        c = fgetc(in);
        fprintf(out, "%02X ",c);
    }
    fclose(out);
    fclose(in);
}
```

With this code you get in your `out` file the desired output.

[*Note:* I changed your `c` variable to an `unsigned int` because the `X` conversion works on unsigned argument:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)

> The **unsigned** argument shall be converted to unsigned hexadecimal format in the style "dddd"; the letters "ABCDEF" are used. The precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear; if the value being converted can be represented in fewer digits, it shall be expanded with leading zeros. The default precision is 1. The result of converting zero with an explicit precision of zero shall be no characters.